# Docker how to copy dotnet published folder to local machine

Tags: c#, docker, .net-core

I have a dockerfile in which I build a console application. After running the publish commmand within the dockerfile I can see the output folder using RUN ls-la. My questions how can I export or extract the output folder (app/out in this case) that was built to view the files on my local machine?

Dockerfile

```
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/sdk:6.0 as build
WORKDIR /app
COPY . .

RUN dotnet --info
RUN dotnet restore ./MyProject.csproj
RUN ls -la
RUN dotnet publish ./MyProject.csproj -c Release -o out

RUN ls -la


# Build runtime image
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/aspnet:6.0
WORKDIR /app
COPY --from=build /app/out .
ENTRYPOINT ["dotnet", "MyProject.dll"]
```

Comment: Publish produces a setup.exe folder like any commercial software and can be transferred to deploy computer lots of ways.  You can put folder on a DVD, transfer using FTP, Copy from a shard drive.  You may want to ZIP folder to make it easier to transfer.

Comment: @jdweng im just looking for a way to extract the files from the docker build to my local machine

Comment: Just run the setup.exe

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can run the container and copy the files to a mounted directory. On Linux, you can mount the current directory and copy like this (replace `<image name>` with the name of your image)

```
docker run --rm -v $(pwd):/dest --entrypoint bash <image name> -c "cp * /dest/"
```

On Windows, you can do this instead from a command prompt (it doesn't work in Powershell)

```
docker run --rm -v %cd%:/dest --entrypoint bash <image name> -c "cp * /dest/"
```

Comment: %cd% will be replaced with the current directory. If you want to copy to c:\temp, you can do `docker run --rm -v c:\temp\:/dest --entrypoint bash <image name> -c "cp * /dest/"`

Comment: Thank you, I ran the command and I do see files copied. Are these the output of RUN dotnet publish ./MyProject.csproj -c Release -o out ?

Comment: It is the content of the /app directory in the image. It's the same as /app/out in the build stage, since you copy /app/out to /app in the final image.

Comment: Yes just verified thanks a bunch!